# Translate routes itself in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm currently using `JMSI18nRoutingBundle` in my Symfony2 project, and it's working fine so far, but I also need the ability to translate the routes itself, for example:

**Routes in English**

```
/en/my-route/whatever/XXX
```

**Routes in Spanish**

```
/es/mi-ruta/lo-que-sea/XXX
```

Summing up, I need the ability to define the following in my controllers:

```
/**
 * @Route("route.my_route/route.whatever/XXX")
 */
```

Where `route.my_route` are messages from the translations files:

**messages.en.yml**

```
route:
    my_route: my-route
```

**messages.es.yml**

```
route:
    my_route: mi-ruta
```

Does anyone knows if this is possible with this bundle at all? If not, is there any other way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To self-answer this question, I end up creating my own bundle to handle this special case. Now I can translate routes using a special `[]` notation, as in:

```
/**
 * @Route("[route.my_route]/[route.whatever]/XXX")
 */
```

If you happen to have the very same problem, here is a link to the bundle. Hope you find it useful:

https://github.com/albertofem/TranslatableRoutePathBundle